# Phonegap android emulator crashing

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I just installed Phonegap following all of the steps: 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

I installed the latest versions of:
Eclipse 
Android SDK
ADT Plugin
PhoneGap 
Cordova

I am using:
OSX 10.8.5

Everything runs smoothly but when I run `cordova emulate android`. THe emulator shows up and loads for a minute then says:

"Unfortunately, Workshop has stopped"

And the app never loads.

Also, when I run `cordova serve android` the browser shows an alert that says:

```
gap:["PluginManager","startup","PluginManager1650094558"]
```

Then the app loads and the browser will show the default cordova screen that says "Connecting to Device" but the app never reaches "Device is Ready". I have have tried tons of different approaches from downgrading versions to creating several AVDs to test. So far after a good 4 hours of testing I haven't found an answer.